# unique users registration

Tags: web-applications, web

i have a web site, where we periodically launching some photo contests. also we have a group of users, who have registered lots of fake accounts for voting. this is a big problem which discredit our contests.
so the question is - how to detect which user is real and which one is fake.

here some cases we've tried:
1) email verification - doesn't helps, because service like 10minutemail allows getting verification email
2) ip verification - we have a lot of ISP, which uses 1-2 IP's for all users, also a lot of companies uses one external IP.
3) voting with social networks buttons - not every our user has an account in any social network, and SN buttons allows voting only once per photo. but we want to allow voting every 24hours.

Answer (score 0):

There's really nothing much you can do about this.

Even services like Hotmail and GMail allow you to set up many accounts, so a single person may have 10 GMail accounts, 10 Hotmail accounts, etc.

If you use a cookie-based solution, that is somewhat better but a person can purge all cookies at any time and can also use different browsers. Still, I would probably choose this method because it is less unreliable than email address or IP address.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to base registration to phone number - sure some users have more then 1 phone, but not that much as emails. You would not verify account via mail, but via sms.

Answer (score 0):

As SMS costs money, I think if credibility is really concerned, Paypal could possibly be used. One could vote for $0.01, which is I think less than the cost of an SMS, yet it offers good authentication. Of course, not everyone has a PayPal account...